# Casting Multiple Values in HugSQL or YesQL with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, casting, hugsql

I'm trying to cast a list of ip addresses to `::inet` but only the last element in the list gets converted.

I've tried the following but nothing seems to work.

```
select * from ip_addresses where address in (:addresses::inet)

select * from ip_addresses where address in (:addresses)::inet

select * from ip_addresses where address in CAST (:addresses AS inet)
```

I can't simply cast the `address::text` since matches can fail if the input addresses don't have a subnet specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like HugSQL is replacing `:addresses` with a comma delimited list so your `(:addresses::inet)` ends up looking like `(addr, addr, addr, ..., addr::inet)`. If that's the case then you could replace `in (list)` with [`= any(array)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16), use the [array constructor syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS), and apply a cast to that array as a whole:

```
select * from ip_addresses where address = any(array[:addresses]::inet[])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer from @mu-is-too-short is the better workaround for this--using the power of Postgresql to solve the problem.

Even so, if you did not want to use Postgresql arrays for this, you can generate a cast for each value in your vector in HugSQL by using a [Clojure Expression](https://www.hugsql.org/#using-expressions):

```
-- :name x 
-- :require [clojure.string :as string]
select * from test where id in (
/*~
(clojure.string/join 
  ","
  (map-indexed (fn [i v] (str ":values." i "::int")) (:values params)))
~*/
)
```

Which will end up giving you something like this:

```
(x-sqlvec {:values ["1" "2"]})
;=> ["select * from test where id in (?::int,?::int)" "1" "2"]
```

So, the above takes the values vector and uses [HugSQL's deep-get syntax](https://www.hugsql.org/#deep-get-param-name) to pull in each of the values individually and add the type cast to each one.  So, you're effectively building a new set of HugSQL parameters on the fly that looks like:

`in (:values.0::int, :values.1::int, :values.2::int)`